# Steam Installer repair tool

Tags: steam

I've recently been getting a lot of error messages when trying to install Steam for the first time on my new gaming computer. I've tried many things to solve these error messages, but none seem to work for me (I referred to the troubleshooting page from the Steam Support website when i was trying to fix these errors.)

So I was wondering, where I can find this Steam Installer repair tool, in hopes of fixing all these error messages?

Answer (score 2):

## Some ways to fix Steam

#### Rebuild your ClientRegistry.blob

This is pulled off the [Steam KB](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7241-EYON-2343)

```
Completely exit from the Steam client.
Go to C:\Program Files\Steam (or the Steam directory that was specified during  installation).
Locate ClientRegistry.blob and rename this file to ClientRegistryOld.blob.
Restart Steam to allow the file to be recreated.
Test the issue once more.
```

#### Watch out for other programs!

It is known that programs such as [Airfoil](http://rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/) and [F-Secure](http://www.f-secure.com/en/web/home_us/home) may cause problems with steam.  Valve lists many of them [here](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=9828-SFLZ-9289).  Try toggling your virus protection, firewall, etc. to see what is causing steam to be unhappy.  Try starting your computer in [safe mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Start-your-computer-in-safe-mode) by pushing f8 before the windows logo comes up.

#### Try out the Steam Fix Program

This program claims to fix a wide variety of issues.  Simply run it and follow the directions.  The downloads are on various KB articles such as [this](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7247-OPVB-9949) one.

#### Validate game cache

If a game is having problems, rather than mess around with installs, try [validating your cache](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?p_faqid=282)! Cache validation is accomplished by right clicking the game in library and clicking the Local Files tab on top.  Now, click the button that says Verify integrity of game cache.  Be patient as this takes a **long** time

#### If all of this fails...

First, try a restart of your computer.  Give steam another shot and if it doesn't work, it's time to reinstall.  In this [steam KB](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=9609-OBMP-2526), it is outlined how to do a complete reinstall.  **ALL OF YOUR STEAM FILES WILL BE GONE**.  Please, make sure you know your password and you are willing to wait for games to re-download.  If you want, move your steamapps ( C:\Program Files\Steam  or  C:\Program Files(x86) )

- Make sure steam is closed
- Open Control Panel
- Select Add or Remove Programs
- Scroll down to Steam
- Double click Steam
- Use the automated uninstall process

**FOR ADVANCED USERS:**
If you really want to wipe out your old install, head over to your Program Files or Program Files(x86) folder.  Find the Steam directory and delete it.  And, with regedit:

```
For 32-bit operating systems:
In the left-hand column of your registry editor, navigate to:           HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Valve\. 

Right-click on Valve and select Delete.

For 64-bit operating systems:
In the left-hand column of your registry editor, navigate to:     HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Valve\. 

Right-click on Valve and select Delete.
In the left-hand column of your registry editor, navigate to:     HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Valve\Steam.
Right-click on Valve select Delete.
```

Don't do this if you don't know what you are doing, and please, make backups.